# Como obter uma List<string> C# e enviar para uma variável JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo em um projeto Asp.net C# e não sei como obter na pagina uma lista de strings da minha classe.

Como faço para obter esses valores?

Código que tenho usado.

```
       var pontos= rota.ObterCordenadas(this._gvConsultaCheck, txtDtInicial, txtHoraInicial, txtDtFinal, txtHoraFinal, serial);
       List<string> latitudes = new List<string>();
       List<string> longitudes = new List<string>();
       foreach (var item in pontos)
       {
           char delimiterChars = ',';
           string[] coord = item.Split(delimiterChars);
           latitudes.Add(coord[0]);
           longitudes.Add(coord[1]);
       }

      this._HdLatitudes.Value = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(latitudes);
      this._HdLongitudes.Value = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(longitudes);

      <html>
      <input id="_HdLatitudes" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />
     <input id="_HdLongitudes" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />
      </html>

    <script>
        var latitudes = $("#_HdLatitudes").val();
        var longitudes = $("#_HdLongitudes").val();
    <script>
```

Comment: Já ouviu falar em Ajax?

Comment: como seria em ajax?

Comment: Isso é possível com Ajax e JSon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$.Ajax` do Jquery.

Acrescente a referência do Jquery na sua página, de preferência ao final do corpo como explicado nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-em-um-documento-html).

**Script de acesso ao método do C#**

```
   $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Pagina.aspx/GetCoordenadas")%>',
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (data) {
                     var dados = JSON.parse(data.d);
                     var latitude = dados.latitude;
                     var longitude = dados.longitude;
                     console.log(dados);
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                 },
                 failure: function (response) {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                 }
             });
         });
```

***Code binding.***

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCoordenadas()
{
     Dictionary<string, object> coordenadas = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     coordenadas .Add("latitude","2435435736");
     coordenadas .Add("longitude", "5674865");
     return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(coordenadas);        
}
```

Para o Ajax acessar o método e serializar você deve adicionar:

- namespace using System.Web.Services;
- namespace using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
- [WebMethod] acima do método.