# Boas práticas na chamada de scripts javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo algumas páginas que usam arquivos/scripts javascript específicos e não incluo no header do site, pois nem todas as páginas o usariam, gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática incluir arquivos/códigos Js em partes distintas da página sem ser no header, e se isso reduz a velocidade de carregamento?

```
<header>
```

arquivo.js **-- aqui será incluído por todas as páginas que possuem o header**

Outra página específica:

```
<header>

<content>
```

arquivo.js **-- incluindo o arquivo js numa parte distinta do header em uma página específica...**

Comment: Esta pergunta parece-me duplicada desta: [Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1109/129). Já viste essa pergunta?

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada.