# Onde inserir arquivos JS e CSS no HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, desempenho

Pensando em performance, em qual parte do HTML devo inserir arquivos CSS e JS. Sei que arquivos JS deve-se inserir antes do fechamento da tag `</body>` para não bloquear o carregamento e se possível de maneira `assíncrona` , mas e o CSS?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1109/18246)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Na minha opinião a melhor prática é colocar o CSS dentro da tag `head`:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

E os arquivos Javascript antes de fechar a tag `body`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Traduzida de: [Onde colocar CSS e Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625773/where-should-i-put-the-css-and-javascript-code-in-an-html-webpage/6625812#6625812)

Comment: É uma resposta muito antiga e creio que não abrange cenários atuais.

Comment: Se tu sabe disso porque fez a pergunta?

Comment: Achei que hj em dia usassem outras técnicas, por isso respondi que "creio", mas o LINQ comentou uma resposta que me ajudou a entender o contexto.

Comment: @Matheus Isso vai depender muito do seu código. Por padrão, é o que o amigo Perozzo colocou aí em sua resposta. Algumas vezes você pode querer chamar um CSS ou script em qualquer parte da página.