# Clicar em ID gerado Dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Boa noite!

Tenho um botão de remover que é gerado via Jquery.
Gostaria de saber como clicar neste botão via Javascript puro.

Já tentei diversar formas as o botão não é  visto no código fonte, apenas quando inspeciono.

```js
$("span").html("<div id='BtnRemove'>Remover</div>");
```

```css
#BtnRemove {
  
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Bom, primeiro, você não tem um botão e sim uma `<div>`. Agora, o que você quer dizer em clicar no botão com JavaScript puro e por que essa restrição uma vez que você já está utilizando JQuery?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Uma div (ou qualquer outro elemento) pode se tornar um botão também quando vc formata para funcionar como um botão. No caso pode não ser um botão em si, mas apenas tem a função de ser um botão :D

Comment: @dvd Isso eu sei, mas é aparência ou role, mas nesse continua sendo uma <div>. E nenhum behavior pro evento de click foi apresentando, e talvez a restrição de JavaScript pode ser porque o AP 
está tentando fazer o bind quando o elemento ainda não existe na DOM e acha que por conta JQuery. (especulando)

Comment: @Oclácio, esse botão é gerado como? tens controle sobre esse código? vai haver mais que um botão igual na página?

Comment: Não há outros botões com esse ID, ele é único na página.

Comment: Quando dou um document.getElementById("BtnRemove"); o console me retorna NULL, retorna nulo quando é gerado dinamicamente. Quando coloco ele manualmente o console me retorna Object. É isso que quero entender Por que o console retorna NULL quando o ID é gerado dinamicamente e como posso localizar esse ID e Clicar Nele.

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta é baseada no caso de se inserir APENAS 1 botão com a `id #BtnRemove`, conforme informado na pergunta:

> *Tenho um botão de remover que é gerado via Jquery[...]*

Se estiver inserindo vários desses botões, já está incorreto pois estás duplicando `id`s, pois um `id` deve ser único na página. Se for este o caso, é preciso fazer de outra forma utilizando `class` em vez de `id`.

---

Você pode usar `document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click"...` verificando se o `target` do evento possui a `id` do botão:

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   if(e.target.id == 'BtnRemove'){
      // ação ao clicar no botão
   }
});
```

A variável `e` (você pode usar qualquer nome para essa variável) retorna o evento chamado. A propriedade `target` retorna o elemento *alvo* do evento (no caso, o elemento clicado) e `.id` o atributo `id` do elemento.

Verificando no `if` se a `id` é a do elemento quem questão (botão "Remover"), você pode executar a ação que deseja.

**Exemplo ilustrativo:**

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   if(e.target.id == 'BtnRemove'){
      console.log("botão clicado");
   }
});
$("span").html("<div id='BtnRemove'>Remover</div>");
```

```css
#BtnRemove {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Eu só trocaria o nome da function :P

Comment: IDs têm de ser únicas. Quando crias uma função que gera IDs duplicadas estás a gerar HTML errado e JavaScript errado.

Comment: Se sabes que está errado sugiro não dares soluções que criem código errado (o que acontece se alguém carregar 2 vezes em `<button onClick="addButt()">` e que indiques na resposta a problemática de IDs duplicadas.

Comment: Eu percebo, e acabaste por ilustrar, sem aviso, como se faz código que gera HTML errado e problemas de código difíceis de perceber a quem estiver a aprender. E acho isso errado, e que devia ser corrigido. Como a resposta não é minha comento para te ajudar a ver o erro e melhorares a resposta.

Comment: @Sergio Veja se melhorou agora, amigo.

Comment: @dvd sim, bem melhor. Ainda acho que deves avisar sobre os problemas de IDs duplicados, pois o teu código (agora com delegação do evento) vai funcionar se houver IDs duplicados, e não devia permitir isso.

Comment: @Sergio Obg! Vou inserir isto na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está porque não tem um botão no seu código:

```
$("span").html("<div id='BtnRemove'>Remover</div>");
```

a maneira correta seria assim:

```
$("span").html("<div id='BtnRemove'><button type='button' onclick='alert(1)'>Remover</button></div>");
```

veja o exemplo em um run code.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  
  $("#btn").html("<button type='button' onclick='alert(1)'>button</button>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="btn"></span>
```

Para você clicar nele via javascript puro basta:

```
var meu_botao = document.getElementsByTagId("btn");
meu_botao[i].click();
```

aonde meu_botao pega o botao da pagina pelo id dele, e meu_botao[0].click(); realiza o click

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o elemento que você está buscando ainda não foi carregado no DOM,

Para solucionar isso você pode carregar seus scripts no final da pagina, aqui você encontra uma breve explicação:

[Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-em-um-documento-html)

```css
#BtnRemove {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span></span>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("span").html("<div id='BtnRemove'>CLIQUE AQUI</div>");

  var botaoAdicionado = document.getElementById("BtnRemove");

  botaoAdicionado.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    alert('Você clicou'); 
  });
  </script>
</body>
```