# A tag <link> pode ser usada fora da tag <head>?

Tags: html

Praticamente todas as documentações referentes à *tag* `<link>` sugerem a chamada dela dentro do bloco `<head></head>`.

Exemplo:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

> Fonte: [w3schools: HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Mas, após testar no Chrome (atualizado), percebi que a chamada funciona em qualquer parte do HTML.

A questão é: ainda que funcione, isso é irregular, má prática ou simplesmente normal?! Pode haver incompatibilidade com algum navegador?

Um exemplo é a *tag* `<script>` que, normalmente quando faz chamada para algum arquivo, é usada dentro da *tag* `<head>`. Já quando é um *script* incorporado, normalmente utiliza-se em qualquer parte do código (*conforme o contexto do script*)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, pode ser usado fora do elemento `<head>`, mas depende o uso. Para importar um arquivo CSS, como citado, é recomendado que deixe no topo do documento, dentro do elemento `<head>` por várias considerações.

Existem os tipos de `<link>` que são considerados *body-ok* que, quando possuindo um desses tipos, é aceitável (ou esperado) que o elemento esteja no corpo do HTML. São eles:

- `dns-prefetch`
- `modulepreload`
- `pingback`
- `preconnect`
- `prefetch`
- `preload`
- `prerender`
- `stylesheet`

Além disso, o uso mais comum do elemento `<link>` no `<body>` é quando ele utiliza os atributos `itemprop` para auxiliar da construção da microdata do documento. Por exemplo, o [*schema* de produto](https://schema.org/Product) traz o seguinte exemplo:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://multivarki.ru?filters%5Bprice%5D%5BLTE%5D=39600" />
  <span itemprop="numberOfItems">315</span>
  <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img alt="Photo of product" itemprop="image"
     src="http://img01.multivarki.ru.ru/c9/f1/a5fe6642-18d0-47ad-b038-6fca20f1c923.jpeg" />
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://multivarki.ru/brand_502/">
      <span itemprop="name">BRAND 502</span>
    </a>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <span itemprop="price">4399 р.</span>
    </div>...
    <div itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou o [*schema* de evento](https://schema.org/Event) que mistura o uso dos elementos `<link>` e `<meta>`:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent">
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicVenue">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Chicago Symphony Center"/>
    <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_Center"/>
    <meta itemprop="address" content="220 S. Michigan Ave, Chicago, Illinois, USA"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <link itemprop="url" href="/examples/ticket/12341234" />
    <meta itemprop="price" content="40"/>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>
  </div>
  <h2 itemprop="name">Shostakovich Leningrad</h2>
  <div>
    <div itemprop="startDate" content="2014-05-23T20:00">May<span>23</span></div>
    <div>8:00 PM</div>
    <div>
      <strong>Britten, Shostakovich</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Jaap van Zweden conducts two World War II-era pieces showcasing the glorious sound of the CSO.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Program</h3>
    <ul>
      <li itemprop="workPerformed" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Grimes" />
        <span itemprop="name"><strong>Britten</strong> Four Sea Interludes and Passacaglia from <em itemprop="name">Peter Grimes</em></span>
  </li>
      <li itemprop="workPerformed" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._7_(Shostakovich)" />
      <span itemprop="name"><strong>Shostakovich</strong> Symphony No. 7 <em>(Leningrad)</em></span>
  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Performers</h3>
    <div itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup">
      <img src="/examples/cso_c_logo_s.jpg" alt="Chicago Symphony Orchestra" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://cso.org/" />
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Symphony_Orchestra" />
      <div>
        <a href="examples/Performer?id=4434"><span itemprop="name">Chicago Symphony Orchestra</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.jaapvanzweden.com/" />
      <img itemprop="image" src="/examples/jvanzweden_s.jpg" alt="Jaap van Zweden"/>
      <div>
        <a href="/examples/Performer.aspx?id=11324"><span itemprop="name">Jaap van Zweden</span></a>
      </div>
      <div>conductor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Segundo a [documentação dele](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) (corroborada com a [especificação](https://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#allowed-in-the-body)) é possível usar dentro do `<body>` também, mas não é recomendado até porque não faz sentido. Sua função é algo que deveria ser executada antes de qualquer renderização e colocar depois não poderá alterar valores já associados ao documento antes.

O que eu costumo dizer é só usar aquilo que lhe traz uma vantagem clara e que você entende bem o que está fazendo. Não consigo ver uma vantagem para usá-la em `<body>`, então ignore que é possível e trate como se fosse proibido, até que consiga dar uma boa justificativa. Outras pessoas tentaram e não acharam.

Pode haver incompatibilidade com algum navegador sempre, porque nenhum navegador é obrigado seguir todas as regras da W3C, apenas deveria para manter o padrão.

`<script>` faz um pouco mais de sentido porque tem a questão do escopo, mesmo assim não deveria ser usado de forma tão solta, em códigos mais organizados não precisa ter em outras partes do código HTML. Existe até uma [questão de performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83867/101).