# DropDown não funciona com responsividade (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde, no código abaixo que eu fiz, quando eu aciono o dropdown com a página responsiva, ele vai e volta, não permanece "aberto/abaixado", vi que poderia ser a ordem das importações, deixei as referentes ao menu por último mas não resolveu, o que mais pode ser ?

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>


    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <!-- Fontes -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Footer -->
     <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS notícias -->
    <link href="css/noticias.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Flip Card -->
    <link href="css/flipcard.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <!-- Slider de depoimentos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/depoimento.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Galeria bootstrap -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/galeria.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="js/galeria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Ancora com JS -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/ancora.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- CSS Complementar -->
    <link href="css/agency.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
            <li class="dropdown nav-item">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Clientes</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#depoimentos"> Depoimentos </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="blank">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">Atendimento Online</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown nav-item">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Downloads</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.teamviewer.com/pt-br/download/windows/" target="_blank"> Team Viewer </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://anydesk.pt/plataformas/windows" target="blank">AnyDesk</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

.... resto do código
```

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz essa ordem de indexação e a forma com faz realmente está bem confusa. Uma dica que te dou é separa os `.CSS` no `<head>` e tudo que for `.JS` vc coloca lá no final como a última coisa antes do `</body>` Isso não é regra, mas é uma boa prática!

Leia essa pergunta ajudar bastante: [Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-em-um-documento-html)

Veja ele funcionando, deixei na resposta o código inteiro do documento, pra facilitar pra vc entender a organização etc...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!-- Fontes -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- Footer -->
   <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS notícias -->
  <link href="css/noticias.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Flip Card -->
  <link href="css/flipcard.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  <!-- Slider de depoimentos -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/depoimento.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Galeria bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
  
  <link href="css/galeria.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  <script src="js/galeria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
  <!-- CSS Complementar -->
  <link href="css/agency.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<style>

  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

          <!-- Header -->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
              <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              Menu
              <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                  <li class="dropdown nav-item">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Clientes</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#depoimentos"> Depoimentos </a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="blank">2ª via do boleto </a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">Atendimento Online</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown nav-item">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Downloads</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.teamviewer.com/pt-br/download/windows/" target="_blank"> Team Viewer </a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="https://anydesk.pt/plataformas/windows" target="blank">AnyDesk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Galeria bootstrap -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Ancora com JS -->
    <script src="js/ancora.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa prática, mas vou aderir, obrigado!