# Por que meu getElementById() não funciona!

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou tentando pegar um paragrafo especifico do meu documento html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Documento</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <p class="Paragrafo" id="ponto">Paragrafo 1</p>
        <p class="Paragrafo" >Paragrafo 2</p>
        <p id="p3">Paragrafo 3</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Através do seu id (id = "ponto"), usando javascript.

```
let p1 = document.getElementById("ponto")
console.log(p1)
```

Porem por algum motivo ele sempre me retorna null

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você seta o id não precisaria nem fazer essa função... apenas chama `ponto`

Comment: Você está tentando selecionar um elemento que ainda não existe no DOM, pois você carregou o JS no início do arquivo, antes dos elementos; por este motivo que é recomendado colocar os arquivos JS no final do HTML.

Comment: envolva o codigo do js em `window.onload = function () { /* codigo aqui */ };`

Comment: Possível duplicada de [Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1109/5878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, 

Como alguns amigos já disseram aqui, você está tentando pegar um elemento que ainda não existe DOM, pois o que está dentro da tag `body` só é executado após a execução dos elementos do `head`. 
Existem algumas soluções simples para o seu problema. A primeira (mas não muito utilizada) é colocar a tag script após o body. Veja:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Documento</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <p class="Paragrafo" id="ponto">Paragrafo 1</p>
        <p class="Paragrafo" >Paragrafo 2</p>
        <p id="p3">Paragrafo 3</p>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Outra solução é fazer seu código javascript aguardar a criação da `window` no DOM, utilizando a função `window.onload`. Está solução é mais arcaica do que a seguinte. Veja:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    let p1 = document.getElementById("ponto")
    console.log(p1);
};
```

A solução mais "atualizada", é utilizando o `DOMContentLoaded`, um evento disparado quando todo o HTML for criado e analisado, sem aguardar o carregamento de Imagens, CSS e outros. Veja:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    let p1 = document.getElementById("ponto")
    console.log(p1);
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Lucas, de onde veio a informação de que colocar o script no fim do `body` é menos utilizada, ou não "tão técnica"? E quanto a usar o evento `DOMContentReady` com `HTMLElement.addEventListener()`, não seria uma solução melhor do que usar o arcaico `window.onload`?

Comment: Olá Fernando, o javascript é executado de modo síncrono, e colocá-lo na tag `head` garante que ele seja executado antes de qualquer elemento do `body` ser criado. Sim, o `DOMContentReady` é realmente mais apropriado, pois o `load` deve ser usado apenas para detectar quando a página está completamente carregada. Muito bem lembrado!