# Ao subir o site o javascript nao rodou

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema: ao subir o site, o meu javascript não rodou. Segue o código fonte.

Este código esta dentro do `body`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//js/code.jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//js/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".//js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>

<div class="col-100">
    <div class="slider-principal">
        <img src="./img/slide_1.jpg"/>
        <img src="./img/slide_2.jpg"/>
        <img src="./img/slide_3.jpg"/>
        <img src="./img/slide_4.jpg"/>
        <img src="./img/slide_5.jpg"/>
        <img src="./img/slide_6.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js/main.js**

```
$('.slider-principal').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300, /*Velocidade do Slide*/
    slidesToShow: 3, /*Quantidade de slides passando por vez*/
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000
});
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu seu problema? Existe alguma dúvida pendente? Se a dúvida estiver solucionada, considere aceitar a resposta. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo é que quando o seu **main.js** executa, os elementos HTML ainda não foram criados.

Uma recomendação é importar os `<script>`'s sempre ao final do HTML, ao invés de no começo (como você está fazendo agora). Para mais detalhes, veja [Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-em-um-documento-html)

Em segundo, você pode executar o seu código somente quando a página já tiver sido carregada:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Isso será executado quando o "document" estiver pronto
    $('.slider-principal').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300, /*Velocidade do Slide*/
        slidesToShow: 3, /*Quantidade de slides passando por vez*/
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000
    });
});
```